# How to SetTimeout Function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question.

I have a function that scans devices and if a devices was found it will be connect.

Now my problem is that this function could crash for a reason x.

If it gets stuck it does nothing else. I would like to set a setTimeout () so that if the function crashes, after a period of time it performs an action.

How can I set this setTimeout ()? thanks a lot!

```
scan1() {
    console.log(" ");
    console.log("-- Start scan device -- ");
    // IF there is error it prints only the console.log above.
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) ||
        (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model))
      ) {

        this.setState({ deviceId1: device.id });
        console.log("ID Device 1 (this.state.deviceId1): " + this.state.deviceId1);
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.setState({deviceName1: device})
        console.log("(this.state.deviceName1 = device:): " + this.state.deviceName1);
        device
          .connect()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("--Connected.--");
            this.scan2();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            Alert.alert("No connection.");
            Actions.homepage();
          });
      }
      else {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        console.log("ERROR.")
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather the problem is that `device.connect()` doesn't error correctly so will just silently die and the `catch` will not work properly.

If so you could wrap `device.connect()` in another promise with a timeout to `reject`.

This gist would do the trick. Javascript Promise Timeout.
https://gist.github.com/john-doherty/bcf35d39d8b30d01ae51ccdecf6c94f5

The only problem being you can't actually cancel `device.connect()` so it may be doing something strange in the background after you think it has stopped or it maybe a problem to re-try. The best thing would be to check out the `device.connect()` and see if you can pass it a callback that can actually reject the promise. If you can't this should work.

```
function promiseTimeout(ms, promise){

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    // create a timeout to reject promise if not resolved
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        reject(
            // Do whatever you want here after the timeout            
        );
    }, ms);

    promise
        .then(function(res){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            reject(err);
        });
  });
};

scan1() {
    console.log(" ");
    console.log("-- Start scan device -- ");
    // IF there is error it prints only the console.log above.
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) ||
        (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model))
      ) {

        this.setState({ deviceId1: device.id });
        console.log("ID Device 1 (this.state.deviceId1): " + this.state.deviceId1);
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.setState({deviceName1: device})
        console.log("(this.state.deviceName1 = device:): " + this.state.deviceName1);

promiseTimeout(device.connect(), 500)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("--Connected.--");
    this.scan2();
  })
  .catch(() => {
    Alert.alert("No connection.");
    Actions.homepage();
  });
}
      else {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        console.log("ERROR.")
      }
    });
  }
```